# Resharper ultimate fails to install extentions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Resharper ultimate 2016.3 fails to install extensions with the following error:

```
14:17:15.792 |E| ExtensionManagerViewModelProvider | The operation has timed out.

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [WebException]
Message = “The operation has timed out.”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.Net.WebException
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509
Source = System
StackTraceString = “
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
     at NuGet.HttpClient.DownloadData(Stream targetStream)
     at NuGet.PackageDownloader.DownloadPackage(IHttpClient downloadClient, IPackageName package, Stream targetStream)
     at NuGet.PackageDownloader.DownloadPackage(Uri uri, IPackageMetadata package, Stream targetStream)
     at NuGet.DataServicePackage.<EnsurePackage>b__0(Stream stream)
     at NuGet.MachineCache.<>c__DisplayClass34.<InvokeOnPackage>b__33()
     at NuGet.MachineCache.TryAct(Func`1 action, String path)
     at NuGet.MachineCache.InvokeOnPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Action`1 action)
     at NuGet.DataServicePackage.EnsurePackage(IPackageCacheRepository cacheRepository)
     at NuGet.DataServicePackage.get_FrameworkAssemblies()
     at NuGet.PackageExtensions.HasProjectContent(IPackage package)
     at NuGet.PackageWalker.GetPackageTarget(IPackage package)
     at NuGet.PackageWalker.GetPackageInfo(IPackage package)
     at NuGet.PackageWalker.Walk(IPackage package)
     at NuGet.InstallWalker.ResolveOperations(IPackage package)
     at NuGet.PackageManager.Execute(IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver)
     at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(IPackage package, FrameworkName targetFramework, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean ignoreWalkInfo)
     at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
     at JetBrains.Application.SinceClr4.Extensions.ExtensionManagerViewModelProvider.<>c__DisplayClass33.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<get_Model2>b__29()
     at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch(ILogger thіs, Action F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
”

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = “The operation has timed out.”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
Data.ManagedThreadName = <NULL>
InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException”
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch(ILogger thіs, Action F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
     at JetBrains.Application.SinceClr4.Extensions.ExtensionManagerViewModelProvider.<>c__DisplayClass33.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<get_Model2>b__28()
     at JetBrains.UI.ExtensionManager.ViewModels.ExtensionActionViewModel.Do()
     at JetBrains.UI.ExtensionManager.ViewModels.ExtensionManagerViewModel.<BeginInstallation>b__10(ProgressIndicator indicator, Property`1 description)
     at JetBrains.UI.ExtensionManager.ViewModels.ProgressPage.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Run>b__3()
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
”
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing an offline plugin installation as described [here](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241675-Offline-plug-in-installation-process):

> 1) Open http://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages in a browser;
>
> 2) Log in to a site;
>
> 3) Find a plugin e.g.
>   http://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/JetBrains.AngularJS/
>   (pay attention, that there may be two versions of a plugin - one for
>   R# 8.x and one for R# 10.x/2016.x);
>
> 4) In Version History, select a plugin version which covers installed
>   R# build;
>
> 5) If you logged in, there will be a Download link;
>
> 6) Hit Download link and download the nuget package;
>
> **Note**: If there are any additional dependencies (apart from "Wave") in Dependencies section on a plugin's page, download and put them to a local folder as well;
>
> 7) Put it to any folder;
>
> 8) Specify such folder here "ReSharper | Options | Environment |
>   Extension Manager | Add" and uncheck ".NET Products Gallery" checkbox;
>
> 9) Run ReSharper | Extension Manager and install the plugin which
>   appears there.

Comment: Tried your solution but it resulted with 'Unable to resolve dependency 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit (≥ 2.7)''

Comment: Seems like you were trying to install ReSpeller plugin. So as I may see, it has a few additional dependencies in "Dependencies" section on the page - https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/NHunspell/ and https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/. I may suggest you to download them and put put to the same local folder which you use to install the plugin itself.

Comment: I added the dependencies as advised by you, ReSpeller was installed properly.. can you add it to your solution , then I'll approve it

Comment: I've just added a note to item 6 in the list about dependencies

Comment: Can you please vote up my question? Since it's a legit one